# I am unable to edit file in NetBeans due to read only message and grayed out editor on Mac

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, terminal

I can't edit a file in NetBeans, the coding editor area is grayed out.
Grayed out code editor
[image: Grayed out code editor]

I was getting a read-only message box whenever I loaded the project, but I went into the directory and changed the permission to read and write as shown in the screenshots below. But I still can't edit the file.
Permission for files
[image: Permission for files]

This is the message I get when I load the project into NetBeans
Read-only message NetBeans
[image: Read-only message NetBeans]

I even made sure that the actual folder was set to read and write and execute permissions
Folder permission
[image: Folder permission]

All these files and folder had different permissions prior to running the `command chmod a+rwx ./` when all the files were locked or set to read-only.

Answer (score 0):

The owner & group & file permissions all must be correct.  I will answer for Linux based systems. But other systems, except windows, should work too.

First change the owner of the files to the user your are logged in as. If you don't know who that is type:`whoami` at the shell prompt.

Then change to your project directory and change ownerName to your logged in name.

```
chown ownerName * -R
```

Then change the groupName to something useful. Probably the same group as your webserver. This isn't really important for getting NetBeans to work , but means your webserver can read the files later (depending on file permissions).

```
chgrp groupName * -R
```

And finally change the file permissions. Note this makes files writable by group members.

```
   chmod -R 775 *
```